# How do I deal with this page resize issue in Safari for windows?

Tags: html, css, safari, zooming

I tested the following code using firefox and Safari.When I zoomed the page in firefox, the text as well as the picture was scaled..However,in Safari,when I zoomed on the page, only the text could be scaled,the pictiure remained the same size as the original one..How can I fix this so that in Safari both the picture and the text can be scaled?

```
 <div id="head1">
        <img src="images/homepage_09.png" width="397px" height="162px" alt="Nopic" title="" id="img_logo"/>
        <img src="images/homepage_04.png" width="322px" height="275px" alt="Nopic" title="" id="img_pic1" />
        <p id="txt_1">Scientific name "crocothemis order – mantodea"</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: I don't actually know for sure one way or the other, but I imagine that this is probably a "feature" of Safari (WebKit). Zooming an image won't actually increase its resolution; it will only stretch it, causing the inevitable distortion, pixellation, and loss of quality. It's unlikely that users really want this. They're making the text bigger for easy reading. The images should stay the same size. If you're using images for page layout purposes, you're already doing it wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try with inline style that could be resized.

```
<img src="images/homepage_04.png" style="width:322px;height:275px;" alt="Nopic" title="" id="img_pic1"/>
```

If it still doesn't work, putting your images as some div's background should be a good workaround as divs are redimensioned by Safari's zoom afaik.

Comment: Could you precise if it's the inline style or the workaround that worked?